# Scope of @Configuration Class in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scope

We are having `@Configuration` class, but it doesn't contain any bean definition and  as it is a legacy class written by someone i don't want to remove the `@Configuration` annotation even while there is no bean definition. Somehow i want to perform logic on shutdown hook of web application but somehow i am not able to get bean from context in the `contextDestroyed()` method so i want to use  `@PreDestroy` on that `@Configuration` class.

Does any one specify what is the **default scope** of the `@Configuration` class. As I don't want that if the scope is non-singleton that bean would the `@PreDestroy` will be called again and again.

Comment: A `@Configuration` is just a bean and like any other bean default scope is singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Configuration` is meta-annotated with `@Component`. This is where its Scope rules are derived from. `@Scope`-annotated components that specify no value (and those without a Scope annotation for that matter) default to **Singleton Scope** as can be looked up in the respective [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html).