# initialization and schedule in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, design-patterns

HI i read this piece of code:

```
@Configuration
@Singleton
public class myConfig {
    private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(myConfig.class);


    public OfflineAttributesComputer offlineAttributesComputer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        offlineAttributesComputer = getOfflineAttributesComputer();
    }

    public OfflineAttributesComputer getOfflineAttributesComputer(){
        OfflineAttributesComputer computer = new OfflineAttributesComputer();
        LOGGER.info("Successfully initialized offline computer.");
        return computer;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 600000)
    public void updateOfflineAttributesComputer(){
        try {
            offlineAttributesComputer = getOfflineAttributesComputer();
            LOGGER.info("Successfully updated offline computer.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new EventBrokerException("Failed.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic function is like initialize a singleton object and after initialization, assign **offlineAttributesComputer** some value. then every ten minutes update the varible.

There are some points I don't understand:

1. is **@Singleton** necessary? what happen if we remove it？
2. in the class defined the **public OfflineAttributesComputer offlineAttributesComputer**?
   should we use public static OfflineAttributesComputer offlineAttributesComputer?
3. why do we need **@PostConstruct**, can we just initialize in a normal way and schedule the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. is `@Singleton` necessary? what happen if we remove it?

Well, it's not Spring annotation. I believe it's not needed as Singleton is default scope, see here: [Scope of @Configuration Class in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016964/scope-of-configuration-class-in-spring)

> 2. in the class defined the `public OfflineAttributesComputer offlineAttributesComputer`? should we use `public static OfflineAttributesComputer offlineAttributesComputer`?

No, `static` is not needed. You are mixing singleton design pattern implementation from pure Java with Spring way.

> 3. why do we need `@PostConstruct`, can we just initialize in a normal way and schedule the update?

From code you posted it's not needed, I mean it can be done in getter too, BUT `OfflineAttributesComputer` is not a bean. Probably the author didn't want others to be able to autowire in other classes...